# Software raid-1 on external drives: Switch from USB to eSATA possible?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, raid, esata

I guess how the drives are connected has nothing to do with raid or no-raid but to be sure I'd like to ask this short question.

I just created raid-1 on my 2x2 external USB-connected drives and now discover I could use eSATA for more speed. So I want to buy a slot plate with two connectors and two eSATA cases.

My board is ASUSTeK M4A785TD-V (5x SATA II)
the disk are Samsung HD204UI (SATA II)

**EDIT** I use current Ubuntu and built the array with mdadm (software raid)

Should be okay, right?

Comment: I will say that in my opinion the "correct" way of doing this is backup, migrate to new connection, restore. You'd certainly have to be mad not to do the "backup" step first either way.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is it software RAID or hardware RAID?

Comment: Running RAID's on two externals just scares me a little...

Comment: I've been running a software RAID on two eSATA drives now for a few years on a CentOS server without any problem.